# Appropriate formula to use for two criteria

Tags: excel-formula

Anyone can help me to return the value at cell G for below criteria . Appreciated anyone who here to participate.

1. if DOS less than 70 days , return X
2. if DOS less than 70 days and code 0650, return empty.

[image: DOS less than 70 and exclude code 0650]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what to do in cases where DOS is greater than 70, so I assume you want it to return empty as well. You can use an `IF` statement.

`=IF(AND(D2<70, A2<>"0650"), "X", "")`